# CSS - sticky footer + sticky "message form"

Tags: css

I have a page that has a sticky footer. In that page, I need to display a list of messages + a reply form at the very bottom of the page. The height of the container for the list of messages should depend on the screen height; the position of the reply form should be at the bottom regardless of the screen height.

I'm using Ryan Fait's sticky footer: http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/. However, I can't seem to apply the same concept to the list of messages + reply form.

Here's a failed attempt at it on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PjCUS/. Any suggestions how to do this?

The HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <p>Your website content here.</p>
        <div class="messages-wrapper">
            <ol>
                <li>Message One</li>
                <li>Message Two</li>
                <li>Message Three</li>
            </ol>
            <div class="messages-push"></div>
        </div>
        <form action="#">
            <fieldset>
                <input type="text"></input>
                <button type="submit">Send</button>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
        <div class="push"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <p>Copyright (c) 2008</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

The CSS:

```
*              {
                   margin: 0
               }
html,
body           {
                   height: 100%
               }
.wrapper       {
                   height: auto !important;
                   height: 100%;
                   margin: 0 auto -4em;
                   min-height: 100%;
               }
.footer,
.push          {
                   height: 4em
               }

.messages-wrapper {
    background-color: pink;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -20px;
    min-height: 100%;
}
.messages-push {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 20px;
}
form, .messages-push {
    background-color: green;
    height: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you:
http://jsfiddle.net/NickWilde/ZRFwD/2/

code:
html:

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <p>Your website content here.</p>
        <div class="push"></div>
    </div>  
    <div class="messages">
        <ol>
                <li>Message One</li>
                <li>Message Two</li>
                <li>Message Three</li>
            </ol>
            <div class="messages-push"></div>
        <form action="#">
            <fieldset>
                <input type="text"></input>
                <button type="submit">Send</button>
            </fieldset>
        </form><br />
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <p>Copyright (c) 2008</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

css:

```
*              {
                   margin: 0
               }
html,
body           {
                   height: 100%
               }
.wrapper       {
                   height: auto !important;
                   height: 100%;
                   margin: 0 auto -10em;
                   min-height: 100%;
               }
.push {
                   height: 10em;
               }

}
form {
    background-color: green;
    height: 40px;
}
```

Comment: The messages and reply form shouldn't be in the footer as that is semantically incorrect. Any other ideas?

Comment: one thing to note: the css `.push` height  and the `.wrapper` height both would want to be changed depending on the height of the messages. One possibility to avoid that would be to have the message div a fixed height with `overflow:auto` style applied.

Comment: `.push` and `.wrapper` needs to change depending on height of messages? I don't think that should be the goal. The height of the messages should be as high as possible depending on screen size. And the reply form should be pushed to the bottom.